# Python: Combinations

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, permutation

I am looking to solve a problem that involves different permutations of an array. I would like a function that checks if the array under scrutiny matches a condition, but if it does not, generates a new permutation to check, and so on, so forth. I believe this involves a while statement, so my question lies more in how to create such an algorithm to generate a unique (but not random so as to avoid duplicates) permutation upon each iteration. There exists a restriction: the array will contain at least 2 but no more than 10 elements. Additionally, if the condition matches no permutations, the return should be `False` I have no code thus far, as I cannot come up with the algorithm I would like to persue yet. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to do your homework for you. You should really put at least a little bit of effort in yourself before coming to ask for help. For instance, googling "python permutations" will quickly tell you that there's a function in the `itertools` module in the standard library that generates permutations for you.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for your response, however I would not come to SO for homework, and I am not looking to print out every permutation, or even generate it- that is excessive for my goal. I need to alter the array every iteration to get a new permutation. If there is a way to do that with itertools, would you please elaborate?

Comment: Like all of the functions in `itertools`, the `itertools.permutations` function returns a lazy iterator object. The iterator generates each permutation of the input iterate on it. If you find an acceptable permutation early on you can break out of the loop and the rest of the permutations will not be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to reinvent the wheel? Since you've tagged python, you should know there are a ton of libraries that help you do useful things like this. One such library is `itertools`, more specifically the `itertools.permutations` function:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for p in permutations(x):
...     print(p)
... 
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

If you must write an algorithm yourself, then you should learn about the [Johnson-Trotter Algorithm](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) for generating permutations. It is quite intuitive, and generates permutations in `O(n!)` time.